# jQuery Cycle Images and Text

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery `cyclyer` to cycle between images using a `next` and `previous` button.  The picture I am cycling is located on the center of my page.  In addition to the picture, there is text (matching the picture) which should change when the picture cycles.  An example can be seen [here](http://www.pizzeriamarcello.sk/ibk/index.html).

I cannot use `alt=''` on the images and just display that text, since I want some styling to be applied to the `div` where the text is displayed.  Is there a way this text change can be done using jQuery?

Comment: If you're using jQuery Cycle, you can use `div`s or `figure`s to wrap the image and text all up in a single block-level container; the plugin will treat each container as a single slide. See [example](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html) (or [this example](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php) for Cycle2).

Comment: You should add that as an answer @Blazemonger ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an array of possible text, and update the text within the text box...

```
var textArray = [];
textArray[0] = "This is the text for the first image";
textArray[1] = "This is the text for the second image";
textArray[2] = "This is the text for the third image";
```

Then give each image a unique identifier like:

```
<img id="image_0" src="picture1.jpg" />
<img id="image_1" src="picture2.jpg" />
<img id="image_2" src="picture3.jpg" />
```

And when the images cycle, do a simple lookup and replace

```
//get the identifier from the image ID, assuming that 'this' 
//refers to the image you just cycled

    var text_index = this.id.replace('image_','');

    $("p#text_box").html(textArray[text_index]);
```

You can style p#text_box however you like with CSS

Comment: This works, but I used the option to wrap it in div and set fixed position. But thank you very much, I will use this for sure in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery Cycle, you can use `div`s or `figure`s to wrap the image and text all up in a single block-level container; the plugin will treat each container as a single slide. See [example](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html) (or [this example](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php) for Cycle2).

```
<div id="slideshow2" class="pics">
    <figure>
        <a href="images/1.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/1m.jpg"></a>
        <figcaption>Text text text text</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="images/2.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/2m.jpg"></a>
        <figcaption>Text text text text</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="images/3.jpg" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/3m.jpg"></a>
        <figcaption>Text text text text</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Then by using CSS positioning, you can put that `figcaption` anywhere else on the page you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wrapped it in div and set fixed position to place I need. It was actually pretty easy, but I didnt figured it out.  Thanks again!